# Autocomplete files/paths while typing in any mode or fundamental mode, like bash does at prompt

Tags: completion

After opening up an empty file named

```
~/work/aback
```

using `emacsclient -nw` ... .

I type in

```
~/huTAB
```

in the body of the file.
how can I get autocompletion candidates shown? In this case,
any files/folders starting with the name `hu`

Answer (score 1):

`M-x hippie-expand`

> Try to expand text before point, using multiple methods.
>   The expansion functions in `hippie-expand-try-functions-list` are
>   tried in order, until a possible expansion is found.  Repeated
>   application of `hippie-expand` inserts successively possible
>   expansions.

Also see [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Hippie-Expand.html)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...  I use [find-file-at-point](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFileAtPoint) (ffap.el) which is offering me completion.  In scratch buffer (having ran `emacs -q`):

```
(require 'ffap)
(ffap-bindings)
~/.prof
```

With the cursor after .prof `C-x C-f` then asks if I want to load .profile, pressing `tab` I can then choose other files.  Using Copy `C-x h M-w` I can then paste that into the file.  Possibly not the solution you're looking for.